# Expo: generated APK don't install on Android versions < 8

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I’m getting a Parsing error from my React Native generated .apk file. I think it has something to do with the minimum SDK support but I don’t know how to fix it.

Edit

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what is your error ?
write it or take a screenShot :)

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: what is your android version ?

Comment: is your androids version of physical phone is > 5 ?

Comment: The screenshot was taken with Andriod 4.4.4

Comment: you are using emulator or physical phone ?

Comment: My device version is 8.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186625/discussion-between-mohammad-reza-dehghani-and-ochui-princewill).

Comment: An using physical device 4.4.4 and 8.1

Comment: It works perfectly on Android 8.1

Comment: i post the answer i hope it works ... because it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue Happens some times and you can fix it by get Signed Release

you can find the tutorial in here :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

it should fix your issue
good luck

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you set the minSdkVersion in your gradle file above the api level of your device. Look for the build.gradle file in your project and change the minSdkVersion.